# Word for a command that does nothing

Tags: c#, clean-code, wording

I have a method that tries to get a `ICommand` instance and otherwise returns an `ICommand` with an `Action` that does nothing

```
private ICommand GetCommandFor(object o)
{
    if(CommandExistsFor(o))
    {
        return _commands[o];
    }
    return new Command(() => { });
}
```

Completely disregarding the fact that we have different levels of abstraction within that method and we are creating the `Command` ad-hoc (while this is functionally equivalent this isn't the real code anyway), I'd like to know how to name the command I'm returning if there is no command for `o`, either for documentation purposes (we are obliged to create XML docs for each method, also private ones) or if I extracted the line that creates the command.

Conceptually I'd call the command I am returning in the case that there is no valid command for `o` a *null object*, but it is not really a null object - at least not explicitly. I have thought about *empty command* or *invariant command*  but I don't think that they transport the concept of what I am doing well enough. Or should I even create a `NullCommand` for that sole purpose, to make my intention even clearer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP. However, this is not the one-and-only correct word, and you can chose any term you like. Don't get me wrong, but I am voting to close this question, since it is IMHO way too opinionated to have a "right" answer.

Comment: No-op is one possibility as Doc Brown suggested. But null object (or null command) is perfectly fine too - not sure why you think it's not. This *is* the null object pattern. According to Wikipedia, " a null object is an object with no referenced value or with defined neutral ("null") behavior", so it fits.

Comment: I think the meaning is clear enough as written without requiring you to create its own class, but if I were to create such a Command, I'd call it StubCommand.

Comment: "*we are obliged to create XML docs for each method, also private ones*". For those comments, simply put "Read the code". You've met the requirement and avoided having to put a pointless comment in that "doc"

Comment: It is quiet literally a null object. You  created it using lambda notation but it's still a null object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that the fact that the action does nothing is an implementation detail and so is not relevant to any comment or extracted method name. The key thing is that it is the default command supplied when there is no match.

Therefore the obvious term to use is `DefaultCommand`.

Comment: You are right, that it is an implementation detail. So should I simply go and state that the method will *always* return a valid command, possibly by adding a `NotNull` annotation to the method? I just don't want anyone to `null`-check the results.

Comment: @PaulKertscher, it's a private method. Why would anyone null-check the returned reference from a private method?

Comment: *"Why would anyone null-check the returned reference"* - true